# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) when installing cocoapods

Tags: ubuntu, installation, cocoapods

I can't install cocoapods in ubuntu. I enter `sudo gem install cocoapods` and get error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I also try: `gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org` it doesn't help. How to fix it? I hope you help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to disable iPv6. It helped